# Show conditional elements?

Tags: usability, layout, hierarchy

Context:

I am designing an application with different login options.
In the settings of the application, you can turn on/off each of the logins options.
50% of the logins options require additional input fields for configuration. The layout of the settings page is vertical.

The problem:
When the option is turned off, should I display to user disabled input fields? In this case, the vertical scroll becomes too long. Is it user-friendly, to show input fields only when option in turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should hide input fields that are currently not relevant for the selected input option.

If you look at this simple example below you can imagine that multiple input fields would quickly become confusing. This is even more so the case if you offer not only the option to log in, but also to sign up.

[image]